# What is the best practice to handle repitetive ZeroDivision exceptions in Python?

Tags: python, exception, divide-by-zero

I have too many same try/except statements. What is the best way for writing code like this? Maybe create some function, that takes statement like g = k/y and return result or 0?

```
try:
    g = k/y
except ZeroDivisionError:
    g = 0.00
    
try:
    m = e/w
except ZeroDivisionError:
    m = 0.00
    
try:
    q = w/h
except ZeroDivisionError:
    q = 0.00
    
try:
    f = i/o
except ZeroDivisionError:
    f = 0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about actually checking for that condition?

```
g = k/y if y != 0 else 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn this into a function! Here are a couple ways of doing it with timing included.

```py
import time

def safe_divide(a, b):
    'Divides a/b, returns 0 if b is 0'
    return a/b if b != 0 else 0

def safe_divide_try_except(a, b):
    'Tries to divide a/b, returns 0 if b is 0'
    try:
        return a/b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

def time_function(divide_function, function_name, list_of_divisors, divisor_name):
    start_time = time.time()
    for a, b in list_of_divisors:
        divide_function(a, b)
    end_time = time.time()
    time_elapsed = end_time - start_time
    print(f'{function_name} {divisor_name} Time: {time_elapsed}')

exceptions = [(a, 0) for a in range(1000000)]
non_exceptions = [(a, 3) for a in range(100000)]
time_function(safe_divide, "Safe Divide", exceptions, "Zero Divide")
time_function(safe_divide_try_except, "Try Except", exceptions, "Zero Divide")
time_function(safe_divide, "Safe Divide", non_exceptions, "Safe Divide")
time_function(safe_divide_try_except, "Try Except", non_exceptions, "Safe Divide")
```

Output:

```
Safe Divide Zero Divide Time: 0.10719704627990723
Try Except Zero Divide Time: 0.34455204010009766
Safe Divide Safe Divide Time: 0.016250133514404297
Try Except Safe Divide Time: 0.01636195182800293
```

Based on my experimentation it looks like using the ternary operator is faster for handling the zero case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that does that and call it when needed:

```
def div_or_zero(a, b):
    try:
        return a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0.0

g = div_or_zero(k, y)
m = div_or_zero(e, w)
q = div_or_zero(w, h)
f = div_or_zero(i, o)
```